# Python - Best Matching from List

Tags: python

This is probably a simple script but can't seem to find a list on Google. I have a list that contains words, and then a phrase. I'd like to match the words in to list to the phrase, and then if it doesn't match to return false. How would I go about it using Python?

Example:

```
list = ["hello", "word", "game", "challenge", "play"]
phrase = "play game"

if 'any combination from list' == phrase:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 8):

Due to the sheer number of permutations possible, it is far better to reverse your logic, and check if every word in the phrase is in your list.

```
words = {"hello", "word", "game", "challenge", "play"}
phrase = "play game"
return all(word in words for word in phrase.split())
```

We can achieve this very easily with [the `all()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all), and a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

We split the phrase into words with [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), then check each word to see if it is in `words` (the variable name `list` smashes the built-in `list()` function, and should not be used).

Note also the change to a set, as a membership test on a set is significantly faster than on a list. As a long phrase may do many membership tests in this function, we want that operation to be as efficient as possible.

A set literal just uses curly braces instead of square brackets - if you have an existing list, not a literal, you can just use [the `set()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-set) to construct a set. E.g: `words = set(some_list)`.

Comment: i think he wants `any()` not `all()`, since his code says `if 'any combination from list' == phrase:`

Comment: No, I thought the same at the beginning, but he means "any combination" of words from the list gives the exact sentence.

Comment: @Stephan It's the reversal of the logic - the phrase must be any combination of words from the list, meaning *all* words in the phrase must be in the list (or set, in this case).

Answer (score 2):

```
list = ["hello", "word", "game", "challenge", "play"]
phrase = "play game"

if all((term in list) for term in phrase.split()):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

With the fewest possible changes to your code, this should make sure that EVERY word in your phrase is found the list.

If you wanted to make sure that ONE of the words in your phrase is in the list, change `all()` to `any()`.

Comment: This is pretty inefficient as a membership test on a list is relatively expensive.

Comment: @Lattyware your answer also does a membership test on a set i dont think he wanted optimization i think he wanted an answer

Comment: For such a small list I can't imagine that converting to a set is significantly more performant.

Comment: @Wooble It's safe to assume that an example given in a question might be a simple one to demonstrate the problem. Yes, at this size - neither method will have a significant difference in performance, but it's worth providing the best method for any potential case where performance could be an issue.

Comment: @Stephan A membership test on a set is significantly more efficient than one on a list. Optimisation may not be the aim, but it makes sense to provide optimisations where possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import itertools
list = ["hello", "word", "game", "challenge", "play"]
phrase = "play game"

length  = len(phrase.split(' '))

for perm in itertools.permutations(list, length):
    if ' '.join(perm) == phrase:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Note this is a pretty inefficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
words = ["hello", "word", "game", "challenge", "play"]
phrase = "play game"

p = phrase.split(" ");

for i in p:

    if not i in words:

        return False

return True
```

Its a very simple way to do this. Though it involves a few more lines of code. You can refer @Lattyware's Answer, Which I felt is the best way to do this!